# Model in Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, javascript-framework

In Knockout.js MVVM framework, is the Model separate from ViewModel OR are there is no separate Model, the ViewModel does the work of representing the domain data (Model) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model in KO is the json data object (Like f0x points out there is no such thing as a JSON object but I think you get the idea)  this can be used directly with knockout to glue together the data with the DOM. But for most cases a ViewModel is needed to add additional features to the model (Features more closely coupled to the GUI, like two way binding using observables).

Comment: The model in KO is the javascript object. There is no such thing as a json object. it's by definition a string.

Comment: I know but people call it that so its a common term these days, I edited my answer to clarify that

Answer (score 2):

KO gives you ViewModel and leave it up to you, what to use as a model.
KO also able to create two-way binding between view and view-model.
It doesn't do anything else.

Comment: I agree with vittore. To be clear, I think MVVM in general do talk about a Model separate from the ViewModel. In that sense, the Model is the "real model", only representing data and domain logic, while the ViewModel adapts this model to the view, adding commands like click handlers and various presentations of data. The same model can then be presented differently in different ViewModels. BUT: Knockout, being a MVVM framework, only explicitly supports the ViewModel (apart from maybe "ko.toJS()").